# SharePoint Video Question

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, video

How long does a video have to play before it counts as a "view" on a SharePoint site?  Does it have to play for a certain amount of seconds, or is it as soon as someone clicks play?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Stream web part in SharePoint online, the video view count is only counted when a user watches a video for a specific amount of time AND a view count is only counted for each user every 24 hours.

Similar issue:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-stream-forum/stream-video-views/m-p/80613

If this is not feasible for you, please feel free to reply.